# How to set the number of digits of F statistic in `linearHypothesis()` in r

Tags: r, digits, hypothesis-test

I run the hypothesis test and the F-statistic has no decimals `(F=106)`. I was wondering if there's a way that F-stat can have digits such that it is a 2 decimal digit number.

```
library(car)
library(jtools)
library(huxtable)
nullhyp <- c("tbilrate+infl=0", "lgdp=1",  "yr=0")
linearHypothesis(reg_ur, nullhyp)
```

[image]

Comment: Please leave it as is. `106` and `106.00` are mathematically different, since the latter indicates that the result was rounded to 2 decimal digits.

Comment: @jay.sf, F stat is supposed to be `106.45`. So I think they just ignore the decimals. I wonder if there's a way I can display the decimals.

Comment: Can't help you unless you make a self-contained reproducible example.

Comment: Use `Results <- linearHypothesis(reg_ur, nullhyp)` and then `print(Results, digits=5)`. Adjust the value of digits= to print as many or as few decimals as you want.

Comment: If you are using huxtable, you can adjust the number of decimal places in a table cell by e.g. `number_format(h)[2,5] <- 3` (for 3 decimal places).